# Streaming Api consumption

Tags: c#, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I have an api http://oversea-download.hikvision.com/uploadfile/Leaflet/ISAPI/HIKVISION%20ISAPI_2.0-IPMD%20Service.pdf I want to receive which uses a HTTP get and wants connection keep-alive.

Once connected it sends XML responses which I want to deserialise. I've created a class to represent the data structure, but I'm not sure how to continually update a list or similar as and when the data is sent back, for example the response (from wireshark) looks like:

[image: wireshark]

I'm not concerned with the parsing of data and updating the list, more how I can keep listening on a socket and see that its XML data and needs to be serialised.. without processing the stream into a buffer and looking for delimiters?

So far the code I had been unsuccessfully playing with looks like:

```
    public static async Task NewTask()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.0.152:80/");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin", "ThePassword");
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        var request = new RestRequest("ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        IRestResponse<EventNotificationAlert> response2 = client.Execute<EventNotificationAlert>(request);
        var name = response2.Data.eventType;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        //var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<EventNotificationAlert>(request, response => {
        //    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.eventDescription);
        //});
    }
```

and the class:

```
    public class EventNotificationAlert
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string ipAddress { get; set; }
    public string portNo { get; set; }
    public string protocol { get; set; }
    public string macAddress { get; set; }
    public string channelID { get; set; }
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public string activePostCount { get; set; }
    public string eventType { get; set; }
    public string eventState { get; set; }
    public string eventDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Let's start with what problem you are trying to solve. Is that the payload is so gigantic that you don't want to load it all into memory? Or is it that it updates very frequently and you need near-real-time notifications of those updates?

Comment: apologies for the confusing post the fact that i have said streaming is probably confusing.. The device keeps sending updates each time an event changes - somehow I want to consume these and my plan was to then put them in an observable collection or something using rx. The payload is as big as I posted above - the device in question has 8 inputs that could generate alerts.. 

I'm guessing the issue is that I don't think using a tcp socket then parsing strings for xml attributes is the best way and feels like there is a library out there that will deal with the majority.

Comment: ok so this kind of works..

```csharp

Comment: "The device keeps sending updates". To what? To their own servers, which you must then call? Or can you "subscribe" to these events by having them sent to a URI of your choosing that you can then handle?

Comment: Disregard my answer. Just noticed the `/alertStream` bit in your code and found that in the doc. So it looks like they are in fact doing server push.

Comment: kind of got something working with            

          var request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.152:80/ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream");
request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
            {
                var req = (WebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
                using (var response = req.EndGetResponse(ar))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    // This loop goes as long as the api is streaming
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {

Answer (score 2):

disregard my comment, can't format it.. this kind of works.. but given I get boundary and content-type text I've got crude processing in...

```
        var messageBuffer = string.Empty;

        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.152:80/ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "ThePassword");
        request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
        {
            var req = (WebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
            // TODO: Add exception handling: EndGetResponse could throw
            using (var response = req.EndGetResponse(ar))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                // This loop goes as long as the api is streaming
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (line == xmlEndStr)
                    {
                        messageBuffer += line;
                        GotMessage(messageBuffer);
                        messageBuffer = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else if (line.StartsWith("<"))
                    {
                        messageBuffer += line;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, request);

    static void GotMessage(string msg)
    {

        var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventNotificationAlert));
        var stringReader = new StringReader(msg);

        var eventAlert = (EventNotificationAlert)mySerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

        Console.WriteLine($"DateTime: {eventAlert.dateTime} Channel: {eventAlert.channelID} Type: {eventAlert.eventType} Description: {eventAlert.eventDescription}");
    }
```

Happy to hear of better ways (as you can tell I'm not great with c#!)